# Getting current tid on taxomony/term/{id} without using arg()

Tags: taxonomy-terms

From a page based on a url of `taxonomy/term/##`, how do I properly get the tid (the numeric value in the URL) *without* using `args()`? Is using args() a decent way of doing this?

Comment: What is the end goal? In what context do you need the tid for?

Comment: To sum up, this is one of those questions that, after helpful feedback that made me questioned *why* and *what*, I decided to approach this from an entirely different way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From where this page is coming, from core taxonomy or views?.

By default the taxonomy module provide the `taxonomy/term/##` callback and views module also provide a default view with the path `taxonomy/term/##`.

If you haven't enabled the **Taxonomy term** view then this page will be the default taxonomy core page, in that case you can use `menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2)` to get the loaded term.

For `arg()`, the [document](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) says

> Avoid use of this function where possible, as resulting code is hard to read. In menu callback functions, attempt to use named arguments. See the explanation in menu.inc for how to construct callbacks that take arguments. When attempting to use this function to load an element from the current path, e.g. loading the node on a node page, use menu_get_object() instead.

Comment: On menu_get_object() what does the second parameter ("2") express?

Comment: The position of the object in the path, like `taxonomy(0)/term(1)/##(2)`